# Allow a python file to add to a different file linux

Tags: python, html, linux, ubuntu

I'm making a "wargame" like the ones on overthewire.org or smashthestack.org. When you finish the game, the user should get a python program that has extra permissions to edit a file in /var/www/html so that they     can sign their name. I want to have a program like this so that they can add text to the html file without removing the text of other users and so that it filters offensive words.

How can I make a file editable by a specific program in Linux? And how can I make the program edit the file in python? Do I just use os.system?

Comment: One thing that might work is to create a custom group that only your program and the user are members of. Then, set the appropriate ownership, group, and permissions on the file. To add text only, of course you can append ">>". But it's trickier if you want to put it in some special part of the file. You might consider allowing the user to add text to a certain special file and then have the program periodically read and process that file to add the appropriate text to the file that is more sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question but also beg you to consider another approach.

The functionality you are looking for is usually handled by a database. If you don't want to use anything more complex, SQLite is often all you need. You would then need a simple web application that connects to the database, grabs the fields, and then injects them into HTML.

I'd use Flask for this as it comes with Jinja and that's a pretty simple stack to get started with.

If you really want to edit the HTML file directly in Python, you will need write permissions for whatever user is running the Python script. On Ubuntu, that folder is typically owned by www-data if you are running Apache.

Then you'd open the file in Python, perform file operations on it, and then close it.

`with open("/var/www/html/somefile.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("l33t h4x0r has completed the challenge!\n")`

That's an example of how you'd do a simple append operation in Python.